# Designing sql, indexes for count(*) query performance

Tags: oracle, count, indexing, oracle10g, olap

Hello all :) I'm building a tool to do some volume sampling on our Oracle 10g database. Here is the query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM product
JOIN customer ON product.CUSTOMER_ID = customer.ID
WHERE 
 (    product.CATEGORY = 'some first category criteria'
  AND customer.REGION = 'some first region criteria'
  AND ...)
 OR
 (    product.CATEGORY = 'some second category criteria'
  AND customer.REGION = 'some second region criteria'
  AND ...)
 OR ...
```

All I need from this query is doing counts. The thing is the volumes are big: about 30 milion rows on each table, and I'd like this query to be responsive.

So far, having composite indexes on `customer (<search criteria column>, CUSTOMER_ID)` has helped a lot. I think it ha helper Oracle go the `JOIN` after an indexed filter operation.

Each `(... AND ... AND ...)` block is expected to contain roughly 50 000 rows. The columns used in the search criteria all have values in sets sized around 1000 values.

I was wondering what approach I could implement regarding the fact that I'll only do `count(*)`s, especially since Oracle has a built-in OLAP module (and a CUBE operation?). Also, I'm sure things can be improved a lot by well thought indexes and hints.

How would you design this?

Comment: indexes are not free.  I would not add new indexes on these large tables just to support your count app.  Also, how fresh do these counts need to be?

Comment: @tbone The data on both colomns will only be refreshed once a day at most. So some precalculation can be sone at night.

Comment: that may be your answer then.  Precalc using a simple materialized view holding the counts you need.  Then point your app at the mat view, and refresh it off hours daily.

Comment: @tbone Problem is, each criteria has about 1000 possibilities. With 5 search criteria that's 1000^5 different cases to count :/

Comment: you can still precalc it, you are really doing DW / analytics work. You probably don't want to run live queries against your production tables constantly throughout the day.  Post your table structures and a sample query

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good candidate for [bitmap indexes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#CBBFJFDD):

> Bitmap indexes are primarily designed for data warehousing or
>   environments in which queries reference many columns in an ad hoc
>   fashion. Situations that may call for a bitmap index include:
>
> The indexed columns have low cardinality, that is, the number of
>   distinct values is small compared to the number of table rows.
>
> The indexed table is either read-only or not subject to significant
>   modification by DML statements.

Specifically, a bitmap join index may be ideal here.  The examples in the manual even match your data model.  I've tried to recreate your model and data below, and a bitmap join index appears to run several orders of magnitude faster than other solutions.

**Sample data**

```
--Create tables
create table customer
(
    customer_id number,
    region      varchar2(100) not null
) nologging;

create table product
(
    product_id  number,
    customer_id number not null,
    category    varchar2(100) not null
) nologging;


--Load 30M rows, 1M rows at a time.  Takes about 6 minutes.
begin
    for i in 1 .. 30 loop
        insert /*+ append */ into customer
        select (1000000*i)+level, 'Region '||trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 1000))
        from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
        commit;

        insert /*+ append */ into product
        select (1000000*i)+level, (1000000*i)+level
            ,'Category '||trunc(dbms_random.value(1, 1000))
        from dual connect by level <= 1000000;
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/

--Add primary keys and foreign key constraints.
alter table customer add constraint customer_pk primary key (customer_id);
alter table product add constraint product_pk primary key (product_id);
alter table product add constraint product_customer_fk
    foreign key (customer_id) references customer(customer_id);

--Gather stats
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'CUSTOMER');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'PRODUCT');
end;
/
```

**Unindexed - slow**

As expected, the performance is bad.  This sample query takes about 75 seconds on my machine.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM product
JOIN customer ON product.CUSTOMER_ID = customer.customer_id
WHERE (product.CATEGORY = 'Category 1' AND customer.REGION = 'Region 1')
 OR   (product.CATEGORY = 'Category 2' AND customer.REGION = 'Region 2')
 OR   (product.CATEGORY = 'Category 888' AND customer.REGION = 'Region 888');
```

**B-tree indexes - still slow**

The plan changes, but performance stays the same.  I think this might be because my example is a worst-case indexing scenario, where the data is truly random.

```
create index customer_idx on customer(region);
create index product_idx on product(category);

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'CUSTOMER');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'PRODUCT');
end;
/
```

**Bitmap indexes - a little better**

This improves the performance a little, to about 61 seconds.

```
drop index customer_idx;
drop index product_idx;

create bitmap index customer_bidx on customer(region);
create bitmap index product_bidx on product(category);

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'CUSTOMER');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'PRODUCT');
end;
/
```

**Bitmap join index - incredibly fast**

Now the query returns the results almost instantly, my IDE counts it as 0 seconds.

```
drop index customer_idx;
drop index product_idx;

create bitmap index customer_product_bjix
on product(product.category, customer.region)
FROM product, customer
where product.CUSTOMER_ID = customer.customer_id;

begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'CUSTOMER');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'PRODUCT');
end;
/
```

**Index cost**

The bitmap join index takes a little longer to create than the b-tree or bitmap indexes.
The b-tree indexes are very large compared to either the bitmap or bitmap join indexes.

```
select segment_name, bytes/1024/1024 MB
from dba_segments
where segment_name in ('CUSTOMER_IDX', 'PRODUCT_IDX'
    ,'CUSTOMER_BIDX', 'PRODUCT_BIDX',  'CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_BJIX');


SEGMENT_NAME            MB
------------            --
CUSTOMER_IDX            726
PRODUCT_IDX             792
CUSTOMER_BIDX            88
PRODUCT_BIDX             96
CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_BJIX   184
```

**Query style**

This won't affect performance, but you may be able to shrink your query like this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM product
JOIN customer ON product.CUSTOMER_ID = customer.customer_id
WHERE (product.category, customer.region)
    in (('Category 1', 'Region 1'),
        ('Category 2', 'Region 2'),
        ('Category 888', 'Region 888'));
```

Comment: I think you're only considering performance of the query.  Bitmaps are generally bad news for tables with even moderate DML activity.  What the poster does NOT reveal is how this table is used by the company (not just this specific need).  I've seen too many tables with a ton of indexes (bitmap and other) because most devs only consider their own immediate needs (and company has little to no sanity checks before adding them). Just something to consider anyway.

Comment: @tbone You're correct, there are issues with bitmap indexes and DML.  Based on the comment "The data on both colomns will only be refreshed once a day at most", it should be possible to build a process to avoid those issues.  It may be as simple as drop the index, modify the table, and then re-create the index.

Comment: I think he was referring to the freshness of the counts.  I suspect that the table(s) he's hitting are key tables used often and have high DML activity.  Anyway, I think I care too much at this point ;-)

Comment: @tbone Ah, well in that case your idea for a materialized view would probably work best, perhaps with a regular bitmap index on it.  BenoitParis - can you clarify if the tables are updated once a day, or if you only want the counts updated once a day?